# HTML weird GET parameters

Tags: html-input

I have a code:

```
<input name="​date" value="0000-00-00 00:00:00">
```

After submitting I get in URL:

```
URL ADDRES ? some_parameters &%E2%80%8B"date"=0000-00-00+00%3A00%3A00
```

Spaces are just for clarification. Important part is that I get %E2%80%8B"date" instead just date. I've also noticed that I get double double quotes so the code in browser looks like this.

```
<input name="​"date"" value="0000-00-00 00:00:00">
```

Why is that?

Comment: In your HTML are your quotes MS smart quotes or something that your webserver is encoding?

Comment: They are just like in first code part (").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a zero-width space in there somewhere.

The sequence `%E2%80%8B` is the UTF-8 encoding of unicode codepoint 0x200b, which is the [zero-width space character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space).  Whichever editor you've used has inserted that in the HTML for some reason, so you need to take it out (I'd imagine that just deleting the line and retyping it would do that, and save you from having to work out exactly where in the line it is).

Comment: That was probably it. I also trimmed value just so it would go wrong. If I hadn't fix it already i'd owe you a beer :)